# ora-6530 reference to uninitialized composite

Tags: oracle, object, types, collections, initialization

I created object and procedure

```
create or replace type rec_int_g as object
( i integer);
create or replace type typ_int_g is table of rec_int_g;

Procedure iparse(v_str in varchar2, t_int out NOCOPY typ_int_g) is
  /* parsing procedure for blank divided string */
  str         varchar2(4000);
  int_array typ_int_g;

  i   pls_integer := 1;
  pos pls_integer := 1;

begin
  int_array := typ_int_g();
  str := norm(v_str); /* normalize string excluding symbols */

  while pos > 0 loop
    
    pos := instr(str, ' ');
    int_array.extend();
    
  
    if pos > 0 then
      int_array(i).i := to_number(trim(substr(str, 1, pos)));
```

Then I call it

```
declare
arr typ_int_g;

begin

search.iparse('1 2 3 4 5',arr);


end;
```

And I got ora-6530 reference to uninitialized composite here

int_array(i).i := to_number(trim(substr(str, 1, pos)));

I have initialized it yet but got error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the record type syntax instead of object type syntax to assign value to the element of NT.

You need to use following syntax:

```
int_array(i) := rec_int_g(to_number(trim(substr(str, 1, pos))));
```

Also, You need to increment the value of index parameter `i` and do substring of `str` in each iteration to remove the already calculated spaces.

I have updated your code as follows:

```
create Procedure iparse(v_str in varchar2) is
  /* parsing procedure for blank divided string */
  str         varchar2(4000);
  int_array typ_int_g;
  i   pls_integer := 1;
  pos pls_integer := 1;

begin
  int_array := typ_int_g();
  --str := norm(v_str); /* normalize string excluding symbols */
  str := v_str;
  while pos > 0 loop
    
    pos := instr(str, ' ');
    str := substr(str, pos+1); -- added this

    if pos > 0 then
      int_array.extend; -- moved it in IF 
      int_array(i) := rec_int_g(to_number(trim(substr(str, 1, pos)))); -- main change
      i := i+1; -- added this -- incremented the index value
    end if;

 end loop;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('iteration count: ' || i); -- output for testing
end iparse;
/
```

Check the [DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Pm8Iu-C).

Comment: Thanx a lot!   int_array(i) := rec_int_g(...   works well, increment and others I skipped in example